# infinitely many algebraically independent numbers without cardinality argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

I was thinking about the field of computable numbers, and it's intuitively pretty obvious that they'll be isomorphic to the characteristic $0$ algebraically closed field, but I realised I don't know a good proof of this.

The sticking point is that I don't know how to find countably many computable numbers which are algebraically independent of each other. With the complex numbers, you can use a cardinality argument to find countably many algebraically independent numbers, but that doesn't work with the computable numbers.

My instinctive guess was that taking countably many numbers $a_0, a_1, \dots$ which are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ would give $e^{a_0},e^{a_1}, \dots$ which are algebraically independent. With a bit of searching, I found this is indeed true, and is in fact the Weierstrass Lindemann Theorem, with the restriction that the $a_i$ must be algebraic. So this provides a proof. But it also seems to be quite a heavy piece of machinery, and I don't at all understand it.

As such, it doesn't fully answer my curiosity, as I am interested in how to prove the isomorphism of fields, not the fact that it is true. And it seems like an obvious fact should have a much simpler proof than this. So I would like to know if there is an simpler way to find countably many algebraically independent computable numbers, which is comprehensible to someone with less background.

So is there a simpler way of showing that the computable number field is isomorphic to the algebraically closed field of countable transcendence degree?

Comment: Two simple clarifications: when people say "computable number", don't they usually mean computable real number? is your field of computable numbers a field of computable complex numbers? Second, why do you say *the* characteristic $0$ algebraically closed field? There are many algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$, and in particular there are countably many countable ones (up to isomorphism), one for each transcendence degree over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I am talking about complex computable numbers for simplicity. But an answer for real computable numbers would work just as well. I am talking about the unique algebraically closed field of countably infinite transcendence degree.

Comment: You can look at a set of Liouville numbers $\alpha_j=\sum_{n\ge 1} 2^{-a_{j,n}}$ with for example $a_{1,n}=2^n,a_{j+1,n}=2^{a_{j,n}}$.

Comment: The sequences $n\mapsto a_{j,n}$ grow much faster at each $j$.